# Why do I get the error object has no method in Chrome debugger when using variable 'name'?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

```
<form name="email" method="post" action="forms/email.php">
    <div id="email">
Sign up for Email
<input type="hidden" value="<?php $page; ?>" name="page">
<input class="searchtext" name="name" type="text" value="Name" id="nameId"/>
<input class="searchtext" name="email" type="text" value="Email" id="emailId"/>
    <a id="submit" class="submitbutton" onClick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit()"></a>
    </div>
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = document.getElementById("nameId");
    name.addEventListener("click",func,false);
    function func() {
        alert(name.value)
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to listen for the click of the the object but it gives me an object has no method error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your variable named `name` collides with `document.name` that´s undefined. Renaming the variable makes it work;

```
if (el.addEventListener) {  
  el.addEventListener('click', func, false);
} else if (el.attachEvent){  
  el.attachEvent('onclick', func); // IE < 9
}
```

Even this will work;

```
document.getElementById("nameId").addEventListener('click', func, false);
```

Comment: Perhaps @zachdyer finds this useful as well? :)

Comment: You are a stud muffin Stefan.